# T-SQL finding the LAST two MAX() times

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max

I need to get four start and stop dates dates from a large table (100,000+) records 
I'm working on a table that contains some data where a ad is moving through our system and I have to find out the last two times the ad has been worked on.

I can get the last time by using the MAX functions like this

For simplicity:

```
Select MAX(DateEntered) AS LastTimeStartDate 
From myTable 
where field1 = 'Whohasit'  and  appname2 ='Ad Workflow'

Select MAX(DateEntered) AS LastTimeEndDate 
From myTable  
where field1 = 'Whohasit'  and  appname2 ='Automated Flows'
```

What I need to do is find the last start and stop time just just before the MAX() so if this ad has stop and started say 10 times I have to find the last two  start and end times. Which would be the 9th and 10th times.

So using the table below I need the following four dates

> start1 : 2011-11-01 16:21:45.830  stop1  : 2011-11-01 16:25:05.740
>   start2 : 2011-11-02 19:28:22.303 stop2  : 2011-11-02 19:32:35.467

Thanks
My table would like the one below:

> ```
> Whohasit      dateentered                             appname2
> Complete      2011-11-15 06:26:16.680                 Ad Workload
> Proofing      2011-11-14 14:50:41.350                 Automated Flows
> Proofing      2011-11-14 14:50:41.500                 Automated Flows
> Complete      2011-11-08 07:09:59.353                 Ad Workload
> Proofing      2011-11-03 08:24:29.520                 Online Proofs Update
> Proof-Pend    2011-11-02 19:32:46.983                 Ad Workload
> Proof-Pend    2011-11-02 19:32:38.147                 Automated Flows
> Proofing      2011-11-02 19:32:38.143                 Automated Flows
> Proofing      2011-11-02 19:32:38.200                 Automated Flows
> Proof-Pend    2011-11-02 19:32:35.467                 Automated Flows
> Proofing      2011-11-02 19:32:35.467                 Automated Flows
> Proofing      2011-11-02 19:32:34.887                 Automated Flows
> Ad Return     2011-11-02 19:29:55.350                 Uploads Done Transfer
> Ad Return     2011-11-02 19:28:22.303                 Ad Workload
> Ad Return     2011-11-02 15:40:48.470                 File Attach
> Ad Return     2011-11-02 15:40:00.100                 Order Entry
> Ad Return     2011-11-02 15:40:00.970                 Order Entry
> Proof-Pend    2011-11-02 15:40:00.800                 Order Entry
> Proof-Pend    2011-11-01 16:25:17.533                 Ad Workload
> Proof-Pend    2011-11-01 16:25:05.740                 Automated Flows
> Proofing      2011-11-01 16:25:05.737                 Automated Flows
> Proofing      2011-11-01 16:25:05.610                 Automated Flows
> Ad Return     2011-11-01 16:23:26.457                 Uploads Done Transfer
> Ad Return     2011-11-01 16:21:45.830                 Ad Workload
> ```

here the SQL code that I have used to get the max of dates I need:

```
Select (e.Firstname + ' ' + e.Lastname)  as Name, awa.Revisionno,awa.DateAssigned, awa.dateAdcompleted,ao.artComplDate, awa.adorderId, nsdac.newStartDateAc, nsdar.newStartDateAR,ned.newEndDate,
CASE WHEN 
   DateDiff(hh, AWFE.dbo.getFridayOffset(COALESCE(newStartDateAR,newStartDateAc)), COALESCE(newEndDate,awa.dateAdcompleted,ao.artComplDate,null)) <= 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Hit1,
CASE WHEN
  DateDiff(hh,AWFE.dbo.getFridayOffset(COALESCE(newStartDateAR,newStartDateAc)), COALESCE(newEndDate,awa.dateAdcompleted,ao.artComplDate,null))  <= 48 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Hit2,

   DateDiff(hh, AWFE.dbo.getFridayOffset(COALESCE(newStartDateAR,newStartDateAc)),COALESCE(ned.newEndDate, awa.dateAdcompleted,ao.artComplDate,null)) As Hours


from AdWorkAssignment awa

JOIN Employee as e ON e.EmployeeId = awa.EmployeeId
JOIN adOrder as ao ON ao.AdOrderid  = awa.AdOrderId
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select adCopyId, MAX(dateentered) as newStartDateAC from adcopylog WHERE appname2 = 'Ad Workload' and whohasitid = 'Ad Creation' group by adCopyId) nsdac on nsdac.adCopyId =awa.AdOrderId
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select adCopyId, MAX(dateentered) as newStartDateAR from adcopylog WHERE appname2 = 'Ad Workload' and whohasitid = 'Ad Return' group by adCopyId) nsdar on nsdar.adCopyId =awa.AdOrderId
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select adCopyId, MAX(dateentered) as newEndDate from adcopylog WHERE appname2 = 'Automated Flows' and whohasitid = 'Proof-Pend' group by adCopyId) ned on ned.adCopyId =awa.AdOrderId
WHERE
 awa.DateAssigned BETWEEN dbo.ToStartDate('11/01/2011') AND dbo.ToEndDate('11/30/2011')
 AND ao.ProofFlag = 1 AND ao.NewMediaFlag = 1 AND awa.VendorId = 'SHOP'

order by hit1,hit2
```

---

I have figure it out txs for looking...

Comment: What have you tried?  If you want to do code-by-request then you should hire a consultant.  Stack Overflow is for assistance with specific issues.

Comment: This question isn't clear enough still.  Are all the rows in the list of rows for a single ad?.  In the query that works, your filter says "field1" = "whohasit", do you mean something like "where whohasit = 'ad return'" - it looks like "whohasit" is a field name and there is no field named "Field1".  It's great to give your desired results, but I see no relation between the values you show for "start1" and "stop1"-how could I know those go together.  Are there other fields in the table, and is there a unique key - a column with a value guaranteed to occur only once in the table.

Comment: It's especially funny that the Sample Data has no 'Ad Workflow' entry =) Additionally I see no reason why stop2 should be 2011-11-02 19:32:35.467 and not the one below or 2 above. Very confusing.

Comment: txs anyway I have figure it out ...

Answer (score 1):

How I went about solving this might not be the most efficient way but, here is how I did  it .
I created a view of the table that has the dates I need. Using  RANK() OVER PARTITION like below:

```
select adcopyid, appname2,dateentered,whohasitid,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY adcopyid ORDER BY dateentered desc) "rank"

 from adcopylog 

WHERE appname2 = 'Automated Flows' and whohasitid = 'Proof-Pend'
```

then in my joins I just reference this view with a simple select like below.

```
JOIN (select adcopyid,(dateentered)as newEndDate from awfe.dbo.copylog WHERE rank = 1) ned on ned.adCopyId =awa.AdOrderId
JOIN (select adcopyid,(dateentered)as newEndDate2 from awfe.dbo.copylog WHERE rank = 2) ned2 on ned2.adCopyId =awa.AdOrderId
```

now I have my top two dates I needed. now I'm not a sql expert and the performance on this is OK. 100,000 + records takes about 4 sec I like to get it cut in half, So I'm still looking at other solutions.